# Maximum Sum of Non-adjacent Elements in 1D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

> Given an array of integers, find a maximum sum of non-adjacent elements.
>      For example, inputs [1, 0, 3, 9, 2,-1] should return 10 (1 + 9).

there should be avoid 3,2 since 9 is adjacent for 3,2. maximum in array + maximum in Non adjacent elements of 9(maximum element in array).

Since maximum element is 9 and next maximum which should be non-adjacent.  resulting this 9+1=10(since 1 is maximum in non adjacent element of maximum).

I tried this way in O(n)+O(Max_index-1)+O(Array.length-Max_index+2).

**Is there any other way so that I can optimize this code in terms of time complexity.**

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
//Maximum Sum of Non-adjacent Elements
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] a={1, 0, 3, 9, 2,-1,-2,-7};
    int max=a[0];
    int max_index=0;
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;++i)
    {
        if(max<a[i])
        {
            max=a[i];
            max_index=i;
        }
    }
    int m1=a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<max_index-1;++i) //get maximum in first half from 0 to max_index-1
    {
        if(m1<a[i])
            m1=a[i];
    }
    int m2=a[max_index+2];
    for(int i=max_index+2;i<a.length;i++)//get maximum in second half max_index+2 to end in array.
    {
        if(a[i]>m2)
        m2=a[i];
    }
    int two_non_adj_max=max+Math.max(m1,m2);
    System.out.println(two_non_adj_max);
}
}
```

Comment: The solution will not always contain the maximum element. Consider the sequence `0, 8, 9, 8, 0`. Are you looking for the sum of exactly two elements or any number of non-adjacent elements?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for your response but in case of {0, 8, 9, 8, 0} maximum will be 9 and non-adjacent maximum in both halves will be 0 so that answer will be 0+9=9.

Comment: But the maximum sum would be 8+8, right?

Comment: @NicoSchertler No no , Maximum in array + Math.max(in non_adjacent element of maximum element).

Comment: @ShreePool: That's not what the problem needs you to compute.

Comment: @user2357112 I edited that Please see again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search for the maximum value M1 in linear time.

You search for the second non-adjacent maximum value M2 in linesr time.

S1 = M1 + M2

If M1 is the first or the last element, the answer is S1.

Otherwise you add the two values adjacent to M1:

S2 = A1 + A2

The solution is then max(S1, S2)

Ok, ShreePool is interested concretely in S1. For other people who might be interested, the only other possible pair of non-adjacent elements which could have a bigger sum are precisely A1 and A2, as if one of them wasn't, it wouldn't be adjacent to M1 and it would have been a candidate for S1.

Now, to find M1 and M2 in linear time, there are several options. I write one which requires only one pass.

```
Precondition: size >= 3;
function nonAdjacentMaxPair(a: Integer [], size: Integer): Integer [] is
   var first: Integer;
   var second: Integer;
   var third: Integer;
   var maxs: Integer [2];
   var i: Integer;
   first := 0;
   second := 1;
   third := 2;
   if (A [1] > A [0]) then
      first := 1;
      second := 0;
   endif;
   if (A [2] > A [1]) then
      third := second;
      second := 2;
      if (A [2] > A [0]) then
         second := first;
         first := 2;
      endif;
   endif;
   i := 3;
   while (i < size) do
      if (A [i] > A [third]) then
         third := i;
         if (A [i] > A [second]) then
            third := second;
            second := i;
            if(A [i] > A [first]) then
               second := first;
               first := i;
            endif;
         endif;
      endif;
      i := i + 1;
   endwhile;
   maxs [0] := first;
   maxs [1] := second;
   if (second = first + 1 or second = first - 1) then
      maxs [1] := third;
   endif;
   return maxs;
endfunction;
```

And S1 is A [maxs [0]] + A [maxs [1]]

Hope this is what you needed.

For the record: A1 + A2 is A [maxs [0] - 1] + A [maxs [0] + 1], if maxs [0] is neither 0 nor size.

Comment: Answer is S1 not S2. S1 = M1 + M2

Comment: I don't see the difficulty, then. You just need to search for two maximums in linear time  You can actually search for both in one pass, but you can also do using library range max function. If you need help with the second maximum, I'll provide the algorithm later, not at home now.

Comment: Added to my answer. Try it on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let `BEST_SUM(i)` be the maximum sum of non-adjacent elements at positions `<= i`.

```
When i<0,   BEST_SUM(i) = 0
Otherwise:  BEST_SUM(i) = max( BEST_SUM(i-1), BEST_SUM(i-2)+a[i] )
```

`BEST_SUM(a.length-1)` is your answer.

NOTE:  This is the max sum of non-adjacent elements, like you asked for.  Looking at your code it looks like you *may* mean the best sum of *two* non-adjacent elements.  The would be different, and easier.

Comment: Matt Timmermans Thank you very much Sir, It's nice approach. It's helpful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 2; j < a.length; ++j) {
        max = Math.max(max, a[i] + a[j]);
    }
}
```

This algorithm has complexity of *O*(*n* ²).

Sketch for a faster algorithm: You could sort the array values with its indices in descending order. Than you can search for the highest pair which has non-adjacent indices. This algorithm takes *O*(*n* log *n*) steps.

Comment: but time complexity is too high can you reduce it. Please

Comment: Yeah it's true it is

Comment: I've moved the comment to the post.

Answer (score 0):

package abc;

public class Solution {

// int[] A{1,4,5,2,5,4,2}

```
public int nonAdjacentMaxSumRepeated(int[] inpArray) {

    int[] a = new int[inpArray.length];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<inpArray.length;i++) {
        j=i+1; 
        //System.out.println("i="+i);
        //System.out.println("j="+j);
        System.out.println(inpArray[i]+","+inpArray[j]);
        a[k]=inpArray[i]+inpArray[j];k++;
        i=j;
    }
    
    int x=0;
    for (int i : a) {
     x = Math.max(x, i);
    }
    
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
    new Solution().nonAdjacentMaxSumRepeated(new int[] {1,3,5,2,6,4,2,7})
    );
}
```

}

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.